# How to inner Join 2 Sources by a key in Akka Scala?

Tags: scala, group-by, stream, akka

I have 2 Sources like:

```
val s1: Source[(Int, String)] = ...
val s2: Source[(Int, String)] = ...
```

Is it possible to inner join them, and finally get something like:

```
val sink: Sink[(Int, String), Future[Iterable[(Int, Iterable[String])]]] = ???
```

Answer (score 4):

This can help, you can use Source.combine method to join s1 and s2

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#combine

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html#combining-sources-and-sinks-with-simplified-api

```
 val future = Source.combine(s1,s2)(Merge(_))
 .groupBy(Integer.MAX_VALUE,_._1).map(t => (t._1,List(t._2)))
 .reduce((v1,v2)=>(v1._1, v1._2 ::: v2._2)).mergeSubstreams
 .runWith(Sink.seq)

future.onComplete{
  case Success(s) => ...
  case Failure(f) => ...
}
```

If you need something more complex that involves more stages, Graphs  can help.